# Laravel: Can't Select Multiple Images To Upload

Tags: laravel

I have  a form that can upload images to database. I can select 1 image and upload it. My code works perfectly but I want to update my code so it can select multiple images rather than one.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Controller File:

```
 public function store(Request $request){

        //image validation 
            $animal = $this->validate(request(), [ 
            'image' => 'sometimes|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:500',
            ]);
        
            //Handles the uploading of the image 
            if ($request->hasFile('image')){
                
            //Gets the filename with the extension
            $fileNameWithExt = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
            //just gets the filename
            $filename = pathinfo($fileNameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            //Just gets the extension
            $extension = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
            //Gets the filename to store
            $fileNameToStore = $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
            //Uploads the image
            $path = $request->file('image')->storeAs('public/images', $fileNameToStore);
            }
            else {
            $fileNameToStore = 'noimage.jpg';
            }
      }
```

Blade File:

```
 <form method ="post" action="/animals" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                @csrf
                <label for="name">Enter Name:</label>
                <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required/>

                <label for="breed">Which animal are you adding to the system?</label>
                <select id="breed" name="breed">
                    <option value="cat">Cat</option>
                    <option value="dog">Dog</option>
                    <option value="rabbit">Rabbit</option>
                    <option value="hamster">Hamster</option>
                
                <label for="dob">Enter Date of Brith:</label>
                <input type="date" id="dob" name="dob" required>
                
                <label for="available">Availability:</label>
                <input type="text" id="available" name="available" required>
                
                <label for="description">Description:</label>
                <input type="text" id="description" name="description" required>

                <label>Please Select Images To Upload:</label>
                <input type="file" name="images[]" multiple placeholder="Select multiple files"/>

                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                </form>
```

Model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Animal extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'animal';

}
```

Comment: Change your code to `<input type="file" name="image" placeholder="Image file" multiple />` and on your controller make a foreach loop to store each image file

Comment: This will not validate until or unless he updates his controller method for multiple images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way to do this task is something like the following. You can take it as  an example code:

**Migration:**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class Animals extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('animals', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('animals');
    }
}
```

**Model Animal**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany;

class animal extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = ['name'];
}
```

**Controller's store method**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Models\animal;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class FrontController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
      //return a view over here for your index
     /*For Example: return view('front.animal'); where front is your folder and inside your folder there's animal.blade.php */

    }
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $animal = $this->validate(request(), [ 
        'image' => 'sometimes|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:500',
        ]);

        if ($request->hasfile('images')) {
            $images = $request->file('images');

            foreach($images as $image) {
               $filename = $image->getClientOriginalName();
               //$filename = pathinfo($fileNameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
               $extension = $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
               $fileNameToStore = $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
               $path = $image->storeAs('public/images', $fileNameToStore);    
                Animal::create([
                    'animal' => $fileNameToStore,
                  ]);
            }
         }

        return back()->with('success', 'Images uploaded successfully');
    }
```

}

**Blade Template:**

```
<input type="file" name="images[]" multiple class="form-control" accept="image/*">
```

Comment: Hi, the error i get is this: Class "App\Models\Image" not found. The Model I am using is my Animal Model name as the image is part of a bigger form. so i have name address and stuff. Should I change image to Animal?

Comment: it's just a sample code for uploading multiple images and store them in the application. Let me edit it according to your controller

Comment: It won't work for me for some reason but i can select more than one image now. I've updated my code for you so you can view it all. Been stuck for a while tbh

Comment: Check answer now. Just update the `Model` with your Model and pass the required fillables and values inside the create method..

Comment: Also try to use `protected $fillable  = ['animal'];` instead of `protected $table = 'animal';`

Comment: Hey,I get the error: Undefined variable $fileNameWithExt. I've changed the model to what you suggested too. What was wrong with ```protected $table = 'animal';```

Comment: just remove this line: `//$filename = pathinfo($fileNameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
`

Comment: I got the error: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'internetapplication.animals' doesn't exist (SQL: insert into `animals` (`animal`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (d.jfif_1619388897.jfif, 2021-04-25 22:14:57, 2021-04-25 22:14:57)).

Comment: ``` $table->id();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('breed');
            $table->string('dob');
            $table->string('available');
            $table->string('description');
            $table->string('image', 256)->nullable();``` This is the migration file related to the animal

Comment: update your model from `protected $fillable = ['animal'] ` to `protected $fillable = ['name']` if that's your column name in your application.

Comment: my table is called animal. the column I'm adding my image to is called image. Shall I add all the fields but the issue is it says base table not found. It's trying to insert into "animals" not "animal"?

Comment: then  in your `animal model` you've to update your fillable columns. Then your code will work. Your SQL Query `(SQL: insert into animals (animal, updated_at, created_at) values (d.jfif_1619388897.jfif, 2021-04-25 22:14:57, 2021-04-25 22:14:57)))`  is working fine. Just update the required columns in your model and the code will work.

Comment: My form wont show at all. When i click the link ot the form it says: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'internetapplication.animals' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `animals`). It keeps saying "animals" when its meant to be animal. I'm really confused.

Comment: updated my code for the working demo. check it.

Comment: @Ramzan instead of posting answers here try to debug by yourself first. He gave you an answer and you still don't know how to proceed then you should read documentation first before coming to stack overflow. It's a platform to just find a solution for the problem not to get the whole working code from others.